# Is it possible to make a polar coordinate chart on Python ggplot?

Tags: python, python-ggplot

Does the ggplot for python have a polar coordinate option?

Thank you

Hugo

Comment: no, currently not :-/

Comment: Is there some kind of roadmap? :-)

Comment: Thanks. Is it a R (ggplot2) example or a Python (ggplot) example?

Comment: We currently have no open issue for that: would you mind posting a issue at https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/ and include an example?

Comment: See https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/317 for the feature request.